# Python: clearing variables from memory

Tags: python, pointers, memory-management, immutability

The below is a Python code to demonstrate how immutable types such as integers are stored in memory:

> ```
> x  = 10 
> print (id(x)) 
> print (id(10))
> ```

**Output**:

140731768218288

140731768218288

My understanding: 10 is stored at memory address 140731768218288 and x points to 10. An integer 10 was created in memory as an immutable integer object.

> ```
> x  = x + 1
> print (id(x)) 
> print (id(11))
> print (id(10))
> ```

**Output**:

140731768218320

140731768218320

140731768218288

My understanding: 10 is still stored at memory address 140731768218288. At the same time, integer 11 was created as immutable object at memory address 140731768218320 and the pointer x was reassigned to that address.

**Question**: can the memory address where 10 is stored be somehow cleared? (again, the example I have in mind is computationally efficient code that deals with large floating point numbers where it seems unnecessary to store "previous" values in memory if these won't be reused for any "future" purpose).

Comment: You don't directly manage memory in python, the garbage collector (or reference counting, depending on the implementation) will.

Answer (score 2):

CPython has a special place for all the numbers in range of `(-5, 256)`

It's kind of optimization they have done for those lower numbers for i guess a performance improvement, you can see it in CPython Code. (This way they avoid alot of creation and distraction of new PyObject)

i dont think there is any way to delete them, im pretty sure python just precreate them while initialazing

**This is only True about CPython, Each python implemenation can implement this machanicsem differently**